# find a node in a tree and replace with a new node with update private members

Tags: c++, constants, binary-tree

I am a newbie trying to learn c++. I am writing a program that is trying to count how many times a word occurs in a text field
My program is storing elements of the class `word` in a bintree. `Word` class has two private members: the string representing the word of the text file and the count. If a word already exist I have to increment the count by one

```
class word {

private:
string myWord;
int count;

public:
word(): myWord(""), count(1)
{
}
word(string input): myWord(input), count(1)
{
}
<ovreload operators>
<some methods>
void addCount(int oldCount)
{
  count += oldCount;
}

int getCount()
{
  return count;
}
};
```

Then in a method that will be called in `main` I am trying to find if the word already exist and add the count:

```
void removeSeparators(string input, bintree<word> &tree, int &count)
{
   removeDot(input);
   word * pword;
   const word * currentWord;
   int currCount = 0;

   <use tokenizer to separate each word>                                 

   // if the tree find the word
   if(tree.find(*pword) != NULL) {
    //get the current word
    currentWord = tree.find(*pword);
    //get the current count of the word
    currCount = currentWord -> getCount(); <--- ERROR line 175
    pword -> addCount(currCount);
    //erase the old node
    tree.erase(*currentWord); 
    //insert new node
    tree.insert(*pword);
    this is the total count of words
    count++; }

    if(tree.find(*pword) == NULL) { tree.insert(*pword); count++; }

    <bit more code for resetting tokanizer>

    }
```

This is the error I have : `countWords.cpp: In function ‘void removeSeparators(std::string, bintree<word>&, int&)’:
countWords.cpp:175: error: passing ‘const word’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘int word::getCount()’ discards qualifiers`

My problem is that the find method in `tree` is like below and I can't change it:

```
 const dataType* find(const dataType &findData) const 
  {
     // this function looks for findData in the tree.
     // If it finds the data it will return the address of the data 
     // in the tree. otherwise it will return NULL

     if (root == NULL) return NULL;
     else return root->find(findData);
  }
```

How can I access the 'old' count of the word and increased by one? I am on the right track at least?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getCount` method should be declared `const`:

```
int getCount() const
{
    ...
}
```

This allows it to be called on `const` objects (such as `currentWord`).  If a method does not alter a class's data, you should generally make it constant.  This gives you more flexibility to use the `const` qualifier appropriately throughout your program.

Comment: oh man I really miised out that. Can't believe I spend so much time on trying to fixing it and did not check that!! Thank you. Feel pretty dumb.
One more thing if I may, using a getter like I am dong is a good practice or there is any better way to do it?